# how do I make an array position equal a variable

Tags: php

what I want to do is run this for loop and within there is a foreach searching the positions. what I want to do is once there it returns false I want it to break and save the position of $i in a variable. I'm using simple_html_dom.php but I don't think that matters since this is more of a basic programming problem.

```
for($i = $0; $i < $20; $i++){
    foreach($html->find('div[class=cate_link]',$i) as $a){
        if (strpos($a->plaintext,'+info') == false){
            break;
        }
    }
    //this is not valid, but essentialy this is what I want to do.
    $stop = $i;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `$i < 20`?

Comment: Are you trying to break both loops when you reach the `break` statement? Put `$stop = $i;` before the break statement to save it. If you're likely to end up inside the foreach loop multiple times while `$i < 20` then you might want to consider changing the $stop to an array and storing the saved values there.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to store the $i variable in $stop ?

Answer (score 1):

To break multiple levels in a loop you simply specify the levels, eg, `break 2` - see the manual on break - http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php.

As such your code might work as

```
for($i = $0; $i < $20; $i++){
    foreach($html->find('div[class=cate_link]',$i) as $a){
        if (strpos($a->plaintext,'+info') == false){
            $stop = $i; // Set variable
            break 2; // break both loops

            // or alternatively force the outer loop condition to expire
            //$i = 21; // Force the outer loop to exit
            //break;
        }
    }

}
```

I have expanded to question to set `$i = 21` to break the outer loop with a single break.

Comment: break 2 is no longer valid after PHP 5.4.0

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I was not aware of this - do you have a link for this info? I cannot see anything in manual.

Comment: I read this in your link: "Removed the ability to pass in variables (e.g., $num = 2; break $num;) as the numerical argument." I guess that tells us we cannot do as you wrote? I haven't tested it though.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld _Removed the ability to pass in_ **variables** , ie, you cannot use a variable to specify the break count. `break 2` or break with any number _should_ still work.

Comment: It was what I meant! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Untested code but syntax checked...

```
<?php

// Untested code...

// Assume that you WILL break out of the loops...

$currentForIdx = -1; // so we can test that 'for' loop actually ran
$quitLoops = false;

for($i = 0; $i < $20 && !quitLoops; $i++) {
    $currentForIdx = $i; // in case we break out of the loops

    foreach($html->find('div[class=cate_link]',$i) as $a){
        if (strpos($a->plaintext,'+info') == false) {
            $quitLoops = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// test $quitLoops and $currentForIdx to work out what happened...

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested this, but I would try something like this:

```
for($i = $0; $i < $20; $i++){
    $stop = false;
    foreach($html->find('div[class=cate_link]',$i) as $a){
        if (strpos($a->plaintext,'+info') == false){
            $stop = $i;
        }
    }

    if ($stop !== false) {break;}

}
```